# Eliminating consecutive number combinations from a result set

Tags: python, combinations, python-itertools

I have a list of 30 numbers:

```
[1, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 15, 19, 20, 22, 23, 24, 26, 27, 28, 32, 33, 35, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 47, 48]
```

I'm printing out all possible 8 digit combinations, which is working great using this code:

```
possible_combinations = itertools.combinations(dedup_list, 8) 

combos = []
for e in possible_combinations:
    combos.append(e)
print combos
```

What I'd like to do now is eliminate ALL combinations containing consecutive 3 digit numbers, for example:

> `[1, 5, 9,`**22,  23,  24,** `33, 37]`

Suggestions?

Comment: How do you want to handle consecutive sequences of length greater than length 3?  What's the desired output for 1,20,21,22,23,24,30?

Comment: that's a very good point, because there would be instances of 4 or 5 consecutive numbers. I'd like to eliminate all 3+ occurrences.

Comment: just leading digit or anywhere?

Comment: Do you want to not generate combinations if they have N consecutive numbers or do you want to simply discard the ones that match this criteria ? Since these combinations are sorted, what is the problem going through each sequence and checking where two consecutive numbers have unitary difference and verify how many times that repeat consecutively ?

Comment: Anycorn - anywhere within the sequence.

Comment: mmgp - I do NOT want to generate sequences that have any 3+ consecutive digit occurrences. I think I understand what you're saying about eliminating digits that are consecutive straight from the list, but that isn't the end result I want - because each of those numbers could be a part of a unique sequence of numbers. Is this what you meant?

Comment: @Trapp no, you misunderstood my question. You can either not produce a combination if it will result in sub-sequence of N consecutive numbers; /or/ you can discard an already generated sequence that then you found out to contain N consecutive numbers. The rest of my earlier comment solves the problem when the situation considered is the later one.

Comment: Note: You can simplify your code to `combos = list(possible_combinations)`.

Answer (score 2):

I think this does the trick:

```
from itertools import combinations, groupby
from operator import itemgetter

data = [1, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 15, 19, 20, 22, 23, 24, 26, 27, 28, 32, 33, 35, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 47, 48]

def find_consecutive(lst, min_string=3):
    for k, g in groupby(enumerate(lst), lambda (i,x):i-x):
        num_string = map(itemgetter(1), g)
        if len(num_string) >= 3:
            yield num_string

for i in combinations(data, 8):
    if not any(find_consecutive(i, min_string=3)):
        print i
```

returns:

```
(1, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9, 15, 19)
(1, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9, 15, 20)
(1, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9, 15, 22)
(1, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9, 15, 23)
(1, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9, 15, 24)
```

...et cetera, et cetera

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way by calculating the differences (similar to numpy's [`diff`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html)):

```
def diff(lst):
    return map(lambda x,y: y-x, lst[:-1],lst[1:])

def remove_consecutive(lst):
    previous = None
    for i, current in enumerate(diff(lst)):
        if previous != 1 and current != 1:
            yield lst[i]
        previous = current
    if current != 1:
        yield lst[-1]

list(remove_consecutive([1, 5, 9, 22, 23, 24, 33, 37]))
# [1, 5, 9, 33, 37]
```

*Which works from the observation that an item is not consecutive only if neither the previous and the next differences are 1.*

Answer (score 0):

This probably won't win any efficiency awards, but you get style points for the list comprehensions.

This is how I would approach the problem. Make a list of a sliding window of size 3.

```
>>> nums = [1, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 15, 19, 20, 22, 23, 24, 26, 27, 28, 32, 33, 35, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 47, 48]
>>> [nums[i:i+3] for i in xrange(len(nums))]
[[1, 3, 5], [3, 5, 6], [5, 6, 7], [6, 7, 8], [7, 8, 9], [8, 9, 10], [9, 10, 15], [10, 15, 19], [15, 19, 20], [19, 20, 22], [20, 22, 23], [22, 23, 24], [23, 24, 26], [24, 26, 27], [26, 27, 28], [27, 28, 32], [28, 32, 33], [32, 33, 35], [33, 35, 37], [35, 37, 38], [37, 38, 39], [38, 39, 40], [39, 40, 41], [40, 41, 42], [41, 42, 43], [42, 43, 44], [43, 44, 47], [44, 47, 48], [47, 48], [48]]
```

Next step, get rid of the consecutive items, which is trivially easy now. This predicate will get cleverly filter out the consecutive items.

```
>>> [nums[i] for i in xrange(len(nums)) if nums[i:i+3] != range(nums[i],nums[i]+3)]
[1, 3, 9, 10, 15, 19, 20, 23, 24, 27, 28, 32, 33, 35, 43, 44, 47, 48]
```

EDIT:

Eric brought up a good point, the solution above does not work entirely. If you want this to work, then predicate is going to need some beefing up. First, I derived these equations. They perform the windowing operation. Convince yourself that they are true:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
i = 2
a[i-0:i+3] == range(a[i-0], a[i]+3) # left
a[i-1:i+2] == range(a[i-1], a[i]+2) # center
a[i-2:i+1] == range(a[i-2], a[i]+1) # right
```

Then you *could* jam it in there sideways...

```
[a for i,a in enumerate(nums) if all(nums[i-j:i+k] != range(nums[i-j], nums[i]+k) for j,k in zip(xrange(0,3,1), xrange(3,0,-1)))]
```

But if you don't want to get shot, pull out the predicate into a function:

```
consec_to_buddies = lambda i, xs: (
    xs[i-0:i+3] == range(xs[i-0], xs[i]+3) or
    xs[i-1:i+2] == range(xs[i-1], xs[i]+2) or
    xs[i-2:i+1] == range(xs[i-2], xs[i]+1)
)

[a for i,a in enumerate(nums) if not consec_to_buddies(i, nums)]
```

Again, this isn't the most efficient, as you will be calculating the predicate for every item, even if you already know you are taking it out. The price you pay for elegance :)

Comment: This is an awesome list comprehension but only removes the *first* of the three consecutive. (Example: `22, 23, 24` -> `23, 24`)

Answer (score 0):

Not the slick `itemgetter` technique like hexparrot, closer to how Balthamos did it in their post.

```
sec = []
for combo in combo_lst:
    seq = combo[:]
    for i in combo:
        if list(combo[combo.index(i):combo.index(i)+3]) == range(i, i+3):
            break
        combo = combo[combo.index(i)+1:]
        if len(combo) == 0:
            sec.append(seq)
            break
```